# Target links to open in page viewer web part from list view

Tags: 2010, word, office-web-apps, page-viewer-web-part

I have a document library, and use office web apps to open the documents for reading. I would like the document to open inside a page viewer web part. Thus one could click a document in the library, and it will be visible in the word viewer app in a webpart on the same page, instead of opening a new page. Is this possible? And how?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe each PageViewer is really an iframe, so I think you can use jquery or javascript to switch the frame to another site.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    $('#frameid').attr('src', loc);
</script>
```